# Can't show a ProgressDialog from an AsynkTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to show a ProgressDialog from an AsyncTask but is not showing... if I delete the 'dialog.dismiss()' of the PostExecute, this task works like a 'post()', it shows the Dialog in the end of the task. I'm getting crazy with this!

```
private static class Experimento extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{   
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Config.getCurrent_Context());
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {   
        try
        {     
            Config.getCurrent_Context().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {   
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Work, work, work...
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Now tried giving the Activity in the constructor but still not working...

```
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

    public Experimento(Activity act)
    {
        Log.w("Experimento", "Experimento");
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

Comment: Your task has ended before the dialog shows up. It's too short to see. Why are you starting a call to execute all on the ui thread in doInBackground? Makes no sense.

Comment: try to remove your code from runOnUiThread in doInBackground() and write your code directly in doInBackground()

Comment: `this task works like a 'post()'` what does this means?

Comment: 1.check if  Config.getCurrent_Context() returning correct context or not. 2.try  dialog.setIndeterminate(false); 3.why use runonuithread on doinbackground??

Comment: My task takes 4-5secs to end, but I haven't wrote it here. 

It's a long code from another guy that worked here and it's done without threads and I need to put a progress bar while job is getting done...

With works like a 'post()' I want to say that the Dialog is shown in the end of the work.

The Context is right. Changing the setIndeterminate to false isn't working...

Thanks all for the answers anyways.

Comment: dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

Comment: You should pass in the context as a parameter to the AsyncTask constructor

Comment: @W4R10CK Nope, `this` is an AsyncTask, not a Context

Comment: Actually, 'Config.getCurrent_Context()' is an Activity object.

Comment: @Óscar_Rubio Please, show us how you are starting the task. Also, Why are you using the UI thread, and posting from the background? This is `Thread` misconception. Can you perform your background task.... in background?

Comment: @Oscar_Rubio are you calling runOnUiThread for real? or it is just an example? if you are... that is the problem

Comment: @Óscar_Rubio man see my answer.

Comment: @W4R10CK I've been out these days, sorry. I've found the error... I had to run the code into the runonUIThread cause the old code was using asynctasks too, and it has a .get() on one on them. I have to do again all that code.

I feel so sorry... thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove setIntermidiate(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
  Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Config.getCurrent_Context());
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {   
  String result = " ";
        try
        {     
            Config.getCurrent_Context().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {   
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Work, work, work...
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```